Wordpress Redirection plugin - Update Query Parameter for all the redirection rules at once
I am using the Wordpress Redirect plugin that 500+ redirection configured. Now I want to update the "Query Parameters" from "Exact match in any order" to "Ignore all parameters" for all the redirection rules at once.
Where are all these redirection saved and how can we bulk edit the "Query Parameters" for all the redirection rules?
The naive approach is to update it one by one from the Wordpress dashboard which I am trying to avoid here due to large number of redirections.

It isn't recommended but let's change the table in the database for this.
From "Exact match" to "Ignore all" use this query
UPDATE `wp_redirection_items` SET `match_data` = '{"source":{"flag_query":"ignore"}}'

It's always a good idea to backup database before tampering this kind of things.

You can use the Export feature, select JSON (which includes all data), then, in a text editor like Sublime Text, find/replace all instances of:
"flag_query" : "exact"
with
"flag_query" : "ignore"
Then delete all your existing redirects in the plugin in Wordpress (be sure you save 2 versions of the export... one before you modify and one after, just in case.
Then import the file.  It seems to remember how many hits each has as well once you reimport.
I just did this to change them all to 'pass', and it worked great.
